# Change Admin displayed product attribute terms per page value in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, pagination, custom-taxonomy

I have multiple pages of attributes. I want to drag and drop to change the order but I can't get them to another page. I've looked all around at google to find a solution to change the number of attributes per page but I can't find it anywhere.

Which filter should I add to change the number from 20 to, for example, 100 attributes per page.

I've looked already at `class-wc-admin-attributes.php` without luck.

Answer (score 2):

It is just related to settings in the backend for each product attribute.

1) For each product attribute taxonomy, on the top right location click on "Screen options" tab:

[image]

2) Then change the **"Number of items per page"** and save:

[image]

You are done.